# Convert rows to column by date with pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have read the stuff on MS pivot tables and I am still having problems getting this correct.

Data

```
wh_id |  saledate |   qty      |
105   |  20190901 | 134.000000 |
105   |  20190902 | 190.000000 |
105   |  20190903 | 148.500000 |
105   |  20190904 | 157.500000 |
105   |  20190905 | 209.500000 |
```

I would like it to come out as a pivot table, like this:

```
wh_id | 1   |  2   |  3   |   4   |  5    |
105   | 134 | 190  |148.5 | 157.5 | 209.5 |
```

this the code :

```
DECLARE
@cols   nvarchar(max)='' ,

@query  nvarchar(max)=''

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(DATEPART(dd, saledate)) 
                   FROM sales
                   WHERE month(saleDATE)=9 and year(saleDATE)=2019 and wh_id=105
                   GROUP BY saledate
                   ORDER BY saledate ASC
                   FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'');

set @query = 'SELECT [wh_id], ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select [wh_id], QUOTENAME(DATEPART(dd, saledate)) saledate,qty
              from sales where month(saleDATE)=9 and year(saleDATE)=2019 and wh_id=105    
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(qty)
                for [saledate] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '       

execute(@query);
```

but the result is like this

```
wh_id | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 
105   | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 |
```

Comment: thanks Zendie helping me format the question,...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change the source part from the above query remove QUOTENAME applied over saledate and try executing the query you will find the expected output.

`set @query = 'SELECT [wh_id], ' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
              select [wh_id], DATEPART(dd, saledate) saledate,qty
              from sales where month(saleDATE)=9 and year(saleDATE)=2019 and wh_id=105

            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(qty)
                for [saledate] in (' + @cols + ')` ) p '

Answer (score 0):

```
select wh_id,
  max(case when rn = 1 then qty end) '1',
  max(case when rn = 2 then qty end) '2',
  max(case when rn = 3 then qty end) '3',
  max(case when rn = 4 then qty end) '4',
  max(case when rn = 5 then qty end) '5'

from
(
  select wh_id,qty,
    row_number() over(partition by wh_id order by qty) rn
  from YourTableName
) src
group by wh_id
```

**OutPut:-**

[image]

**Note:-** Instead of using Pivot ...you can use this simple query...using ...case when and then with max aggregate function...

In above example....i'm forgot add decimal value in Table....

Comment: thank you for your answer, but i want to sum the qty per day...

Comment: for 31 days of sales